# the superclass javax.servlet.http.httpservlet was not found on the java build

Tags: eclipse, jsp, wso2, jstl, apache-axis

I am trying to develop a web service with Eclipse, using `wso2 developer studio` and `wso2 business process server`. When I create a Dynamic Web Project with the `Axis2` facet, a lot of problems occur, like:

*the superclass javax.servlet.http.httpservlet was not found on the java  build*

*httpservlet cannot be resolved to a type*

*servletcontext cannot be resolved to a type*

I searched on the internet and verified `WSO2 Carbon 4.4 server` is the target runtime and that it is added as a library in the Java Build Path.

Does anyone know could I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have pom.xml ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua in the Dynamic Web Project? no, should I? I was following youtube tutorial and it wasn't used

Comment: Take a screenshot and post your project structure. Like http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/spring3-mvc-maven-project.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/EAVrIxA

Comment: Sanity check: can you open those types from the Open Type action on the Navigate menu?

Comment: @nitind No, HttpServlet and ServletContext don't appear in the Open Type window